# print 2 arrays like matrix for my assignment

Tags: java

I want my output to be like this e.g. if the user inputs `3`:
without using 2d array

```
     1  2  3   

1    1  2  3
2    1  4  6  
3    3  6  9
```

My code so far

```
public void matrixmutilplication() {
    String thenumberofmatrix = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of column and rows  ");
    int i = Integer.parseInt(thenumberofmatrix);

    int[] cloumnarray = new int[i];
    int[] rowarray = new int[i];

    for (int z = 0; z <= i - 1; z++) {
        cloumnarray[z] = z + 1;
        rowarray[z] = z + 1;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.println(cloumnarray[j] * rowarray[j]);
    }
}
```

I tried different options and can't get this to work properly.

Comment: Should there be a `2` at Position (2, 1) (row, column)

Comment: For your printing at the end, you need to nested for-loop to cover the printing of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void matrixmutilplication() {
    String thenumberofmatrix = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of column and rows  ");
    int i = Integer.parseInt(thenumberofmatrix);

    for (int a = 0; a <= i; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b <= i; b++) {
            // top corner, don't print nothing
            if (a == 0 && b == 0)   System.out.print("\t");
            // top row 0-1, 0-2, 0-3 etc... just 1,2,3...
            else if (a == 0)  {
                System.out.print(b + "\t");
                // last line, print extra line break
                if (b == i) 
                    System.out.print("\n");
            }
            // first column 1-0, 2-0, 3-0... just a + space (tabulator)
            else if (b == 0)        System.out.print(a + "\t");
            // any other cases, are candidates to multiply and give result
            else                    System.out.print(a*b + "\t");
        }
        //look this is out of scope of nested loops, so, 
        // in each a iteration, print line break :)
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    matrixmutilplication();
}
```

**OUTPUT (3)**

```
    1   2   3   

1   1   2   3   
2   2   4   6   
3   3   6   9
```

**OUTPUT (5)**

```
    1   2   3   4   5   

1   1   2   3   4   5   
2   2   4   6   8   10  
3   3   6   9   12  15  
4   4   8   12  16  20  
5   5   10  15  20  25
```

But problem (for me) is the numbers are not padded in the natural order, so, to achieve your goal, **exactly as in your demo**, will need a bit of padding like this

```
public static void matrixmutilplication() {
    String thenumberofmatrix = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of column and rows  ");
    int i = Integer.parseInt(thenumberofmatrix);

    for (int a = 0; a <= i; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b <= i; b++) {
            if (a == 0 && b == 0)   System.out.print("\t");
            else if (a == 0)  {
                System.out.print(String.format("%3s", b));
                if (b == i) 
                    System.out.print("\n");
            }
            else if (b == 0)        System.out.print(a + "\t");
            else                    System.out.print(String.format("%3s", a*b));
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    matrixmutilplication();
}
```

**OUTPUT (7)**

```
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7

1     1  2  3  4  5  6  7
2     2  4  6  8 10 12 14
3     3  6  9 12 15 18 21
4     4  8 12 16 20 24 28
5     5 10 15 20 25 30 35
6     6 12 18 24 30 36 42
7     7 14 21 28 35 42 49
```

What looks quite good :)

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you're working with a matrix involving two arrays (especially if you're trying to a solve a problem that deals with patterns), you want to have a nested for loop like so:

```
for(int row = 0; row < numSelected; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < numSelected; col++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

That way, each cell in the matrix will be covered. Now using that, you can try multiplying the `row` index and the `col` index and storing that to the correct cell.

Comment: I'd like to point out that you're output will be zero-based. Meaning the first row/column will be all zeros.

Comment: I wasn't really trying to answer the question directly but rather show him a proper way to have a nested for-loops to solve the problem for himself. Not only that, I personally found it more convenient to say `array[row][column]` then `array[row+1][column+1]`.

Comment: Sure, I was commenting for the benefit of OP.

Answer (score -1):

So this should be pretty simple.

```
public void matrixmutilplication() {
    String thenumberofmatrix = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of column and rows  ");
    int i = Integer.parseInt(thenumberofmatrix);

    for (int a = 0; a < i; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < i; b++) {
            System.out.print(a*b + "\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```